# Communication between Subview Controller and Superview Controller in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

So, I have a View with a UIScrollView. To this ScrollView, I added a Subview like this:

```
ChildViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
```

This works fine. In this Child Controller, I defined a button with target self:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

If I click the button, the program breaks. But if I set the target to nil, the Parent Controller is called as first responder.

However, I want the action to be called in the Child Controller. I'm not able to communicate from the Parent to the Subview or call an action from the Parent/Superview.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?

Comment: “If I click the button, the program breaks.”  How does it break?  Edit your post to include the messages that appear in the debug console.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?...you have method called actionButton right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more to go on, my first guess would be that the `ChildViewController` gets deallocated and that is why your app crashes when you tap the button.

So a way of resolving this could be to keep a strong reference to your `ChildViewController` like:

`@property (strong) ChildViewController *childViewController`

then you would do:

```
self.childViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.childViewController.view];
```

But more information would help :)

Cheers
Morten

Comment: You are right, that's it! It all makes sense now, the action is now called in the Child Controller. Thank you very much, you made my day! :)

Comment: @schumi glad I could help, next time be sure to include crash messages :)